# view.window.center is 0,0 if invoked in response to a notification but 160,284 otherwise

Tags: ios

I was having an issue where a view wasn't displaying if the view was displayed in response to listening for a notification posed by my model, but it was being displayed if displayed if invoked directly from the view controller code elsewhere.

The cause was I was setting the center of this view to the parent's view's window's center, i.e.

```
- (void) viewControllerMethod
{
 MyView *view = (MyView*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    view.center = self.view.window.center;
}
```

If viewControllerMethod is invoked from anywhere within the view controller such as viewDidAppear then the value of self.view.window.center is 160,284. But if viewControllerMethod is invoked via a notification from the notification center then self.view.window.center is 0,0.

I have solved my original problem by changing self.view.window.center to self.view.center.

But I am curious to know why the window's center has a different value depending upon how it is invoked?

In both cases self.view.center is 160,284, it is only self.view.window.center that has different values.

(Note that even after forcing viewControllerMethod to be invoked on the main thread it still exhibits this behavior).

Answer (score 2):

It's not that window's center has a different value, it's that window probably didn't exist at all.  According to the UIView docs, window is nil if the view hasn't been added to a window.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW55

BTW, if you want MyView to always be centered, you might want to just add it in viewControllerMethod and position it in viewDidLayoutSubviews.  (Or use autolayout.)